# Set cookie inline

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I'm using to set a cookie:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";}
```

I would like to call this using a button. Like:

```
<input type='button' onclick='setCookie(name, jim, 1)'>
```

The error I get is "Can't find variable: jim". jim is a variable holding a string.

When I make this a literal just to see if it works, like:

```
<input type='button' onclick='setCookie(name, 'jim', 1)'>
```

I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'"

Comment: You're using the variable `jim` but haven't declared it anywhere. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to quote strings like `name` and `jim`.

Comment: Apologies. I updated the question with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. This was an error with my web server.